# DemoKit application wont connect with my ADK board?

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I'm trying to get the DemoKit app to work with my Arduino ADK mega. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2 (I only just updated to it, if this turns out to be the issue can someone explain how to undo the update?) and I'm using API 15. The app launches successfully and asks me to connect to an ADK board, but when I plugin my Arduino, nothing happens. I am using eclipse.

I mentioned one thing that I suspect could be wrong, but I have another. I have a 64 bit windows OS, I am running the 32 bit versions of eclipse and the sdk, but I am running the 64 bit version of Arduino. Let me know any thoughts!

Comment: UPDATE - I have tried API 13 as well and have encountered the same issue

Comment: are you plugging in your arduino into your pc or the android tablet?

Comment: Sorry about the late response, but yea, Im plugging the arduino into the android tablet

Comment: I've had issues like this ... Usually I just have to plugin in the Android device wait for it to register then restart Eclipse and it should start working. Any luck yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the original App by Google? Afaik this supports Android Devices with API level 10(2.3.4+) the USB driver has been backported for this and is used in a different manner than the one for 3.1+. You could try to make modifications according to these [differences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html) to use the correct usb library.